# Use of application name with space(s) with WinExist

Tags: autohotkey

So I wanted to check if certain application exists or not.

If it does and there was no input within 4.5 min, switch to that app and perform some task.

Basically an AFK cheater.

This is what I have so far:

```
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent
settimer, idleCheck, 1000; check every second
return

idleCheck:
if WinExist(App Name with Spaces); if app is running
{
    if(A_TimeIdle >= 270000); and there was no input in 4.5 min
    {
        WinActivate; switch to that app
        sendInput z; and perform an action
    }
}
return
```

Now obviously that doesn't work since I'd not be posting here otherwise.

The question is very simple yet I couldn't find an answer.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinExist is a function and function parameters are expressions...

In expressions you need to use double quotes `"` around strings and you don't need `%` around variables

you also need to have a space before the semicolon to use comments

```
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent
settimer, idleCheck, 1000 ; check every second
return

idleCheck:
if WinExist("App Name with or without Spaces") ; if app is running
{
    if(A_TimeIdle >= 270000) ; and there was no input in 4.5 min
    {
        WinActivate ; switch to that app
        sendInput z ; and perform an action
    }
}
return
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks it did help. But while laptop lid was closed it didn't, but that's another question.

Comment: If the laptop lid is closed, the computer may be put on standby and the script won't be running.  That is a laptop configuration issue and you'll need to change the laptop's "lid close" behavior.